# MATLAB imshowpair();

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have used imshowpair to compare two images and it shows nicely.
However I want to save the the image the imshowpair shows, however every time I assign it to a value (h) and I use to show the image, an error occurs. I wish to have it as a RGB image in order to manipulate the outputted image.

```
h = imshowpair(B, C);
figure;

imshow(h, []);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `h` is a graphic handle, which cannot be used as input of `imshow` hence you get error. did you try `imfuse`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
figure,imshowpair(B,C)
frame = getframe();
image = frame2im(frame);
imwrite(image,'location.png')
```